# How to merge to a protected branch when Github Action passes?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

My current workflow is to push to my `master` branch on GitHub, which then triggers a Github Action that runs my unit tests, stress tests etc.

I now want to make sure that no commits land on `master` that fail the tests. For that, I want to:

1. introduce a `testing` branch for pushing instead, which then runs the GitHub action and finally automatically merges to `master` when passing.
2. protect the `master` branch in a way that I cannot accidentally push to it directly.

How can I achieve this?

Additional info:

- I prefer not to use Pull Requests for this, as I'm currently the only developer in this project.

Answer (score 0):

> I prefer not to use Pull Requests for this

Yet they are a good option to consider.
Combined with the right tools, a PR with a label "automerge" can then be automatically accepted/merged.

For instance:

- [mergery](https://github.com/apps/mergery), GitHub application (so it needs a dedicated server)
- [automerge-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/merge-pull-requests) (so its does not need its own server, and is executed directly on GitHub side)

The latter includes:

> `MERGE_LABELS`: The labels that need to be present for a pull request to be merged (using `MERGE_METHOD`). The default value is `automerge`.

All you need to do is create a PR with an automerge label.

Comment: Thanks, but I feel it is somehow cumbersome to create a PR just for myself and therefore complicate the workflow. For instance, what would be the equivalent for `git push`?